Different conversion functions per file path in Eleventy?
I replaced the default Markdown-It library with node-pandoc in my instance of Eleventy, as per the code below. Now, I would like to apply different arguments to the nodePandoc function according to the directory in which the source files exist. Is this possible?

Code here:
const nodePandoc = require('node-pandoc');
module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {
  async function convertMarkdownToHtml(markdown) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      nodePandoc(markdown, '-d _data/defaults.yaml', (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          // If an error occurred, reject the promise with the error
          reject(new Error(`Pandoc error: ${err.message}`));
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  eleventyConfig.setLibrary("md", {
    render: async function(content) {
      return await convertMarkdownToHtml(content);
    }
  });
}

